# None of my apps are keeping a list of recent documents?

Tags: macos, uti, menu-bar, document-management

Example:

If I open an image in Preview, the "File/Open Recent" menu lists the name of the file.
If I then close the file, but still leave Preview running, the "Open Recent" menu still lists the file.
If I quit Preview, the "Show Recents" menu does not show any files.
If I reopen Preview, the "Open Recent" menu does not show any files.

[image: blank open recent menu]

I have a feeling this is a permissions problem, but repair permissions has not helped.

In Console, Preview is reporting the following error upon opening:

"29/02/2012 14:45:57.183 com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService: Failure to de-serialize bookmark data file."

I'm using Preview as an example here, but it holds for every app - whether they are bundled or downloaded - on my system.

System Preferences/Appearance/Number of Recent Items is set to 10.

I am running Lion 10.7.3 on an iMac 12,1 with a dual SSD and HDD internal drive setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This worked for me:

1. Turn on the Mac whilst holding down <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in order to boot from the recovery partition.
2. On the top menu, click *Utilities*, then click *Terminal*.
3. Type `resetpassword` and press <kbd>↩</kbd>.
4. Click on your main hard drive.
5. In the dropdown box under *Select the user account* make sure to select your username.
6. Underneath where it says *Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs*, click the Reset button.
7. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to quit the Reset Password application.
8. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> again to quit the Terminal.
9. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> one more time and click Restart.
10. Click *Mac OS X Utilities* in the top left of the screen and click the Restart button.

---

I got the solution over at [Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17723638#17723638):

> I'm not sure where that list is stored, but I agree with your feeling that this is a
> permissions problem.  However, repairing permissions with Disk Utility is not likely to
> help.  That only repairs certain things, and doesn't affect the user folder at all, which is likely to be where the problem lies.  You could try [resetting the permissions](http://www.fixkb.com/2011/08/reset-home-folder-permissions.html)
> on your home folder.

Answer (score 3):

I would trash your preview .plist file located at:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.plist
```

Restart Preview, and it should create a new one.  It sounds corrupted.

Comment: The recent documents are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist`. So, you should thrash that (as well).

Comment: I think doing one will recreate the others, but good point in case it doesn't.  I thought that the recent files were actually stored in com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService.plist actually, so it's perhaps another to add to the list to remove and recreate.  But I would start with the main one first.  Check the datestamps on the ones mentioned in these comments to see if they get recreated also after you do, just out of interest.

Comment: I trashed `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist` this is what made the lists empty. Before that they were displaying a list of old recent files that would never change. After that, I trashed `com.apple.Preview.plist` and it made no difference.

Comment: Did you trash `com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService.plist`?

Comment: Yes I did, it did not solve the problem. You use backticks ` to highlight inline code.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry then, are there any other preview plists that you can destroy?