# Cannot Add, Remove, Move, or Drag icons from Dock

Tags: macos, applications, dock

I'm using OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) and recently I have been unable to drag or move any items on the dock. Right clicking them gives no option for "remove from dock", and the icons cannot be rearranged. New icons cannot be added, old icons cannot be deleted.

I have tried restarting, and resetting dock preferences to default, and `killall Dock`, as suggested by earlier askers. None of it works.

I heard about problems with PushBullet - but I do not have PushBullet. Just in case, I deleted a lot of random applications. Still nothing works.

I've tried various commands from lots of answerers on other questions. I've consulted the Mac Help pages. Nothing.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this? After resetting my Dock in an attempt to fix it, it is now filled with the default icons too. This is really limiting my productivity.

Comment: Admin account, I presume? I'm wondering if perms have gotten screwed somewhere… maybe see http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42107/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin will this reset my password?

Comment: Have you tried deleting com.apple.dock from ~/Library/Preferences?

Comment: @MorganR I think I already have tried it, because I don't see it in the directory. I do see com.apple.dock.plist, should I try deleting that too?

Comment: No - just follow the instructions, you're not actually going to be resetting the password, but that's the only way into this particular 'fix'

Comment: @Tetsujin Okay, I will try this as soon as I can.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest Sorry, I should have been more clear. Yes, delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist and restart your machine. When you log back in, your Dock should have reset.

Comment: @MorganR Just did that and restarted. Still unable to move icons.

Comment: Strange - have the Dock icons reset to the default ones?

Comment: Yeah. They were the default ones already tho because I reset preferences once in an attempt to fix it.

Comment: Maybe related to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166999/cant-rearrange-dock-icons/168804

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Dock is not locked:

```
defaults delete com.apple.Dock contents-immutable && killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not locked. I've run that command before, but I ran it again just in case - still no change. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: I had to call `killall Dock` **twice** before changes applied. (macOS 10.13.2)

Answer (score 1):

In Apple menu choose forcequit: Finder is in the list, choose relaunch.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

go to system preferences, click parental controls, select your user account, click other, deselect "Prevent the dock from being modified"

Comment: It appears the OP has an admin account, so it can't have parental controls applied to it; also, you cannot unlock parental controls if you're not the admin.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, simply going to the Parental Controls section of the settings, unlocking it to modify (even though it was already off), then closings the settings window, fixed it for me.

Comment: Was this enabled on an admin account?